# Finding the angle between two points in $l^2$ metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

let $p = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...)$ and $q=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},...)$

I am asked to find angle between these two in the metric space $l^2$

I can apply the formula $$\frac{<p,q>}{||p|||q||}=cos \theta$$

Where the numerator is the scalar product.

$$<p,q>  = {\sum_1^\infty a_kb_k}$$ in this metric. and $$||p|| = \sqrt{ \sum_1^\infty |a_k|^2}$$

Calculating the scalar product we end up with the series

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}.... = 1$$

However I couldn't manage to find $||p||||q||$ any hints?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well known series in this case is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}  =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ This equals $||p||^2$ while $||q||^2$ misses the 1 term so equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1$

Answer (score 1):

Look for Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$, in particular the value at $s=2$.

Comment: He asked for hints.

Comment: Now you can comment.